# Cannot filter out logs from the console

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to filter out certain endpoint logs from the console. My `settings.py` looks like this:

```
def skip_rss_requests(record):
    if record.args and record.args[0].startswith('GET /api/feed/rss/'):
        print("HEEERRRRREEEE")
        return False
    return True


LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'filters': {
    'skip_rss_requests': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
        'callback': skip_rss_requests
    }
  },
  'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s|%(name)s|%(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    },
  },
  'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['skip_rss_requests'],
            # 'stream': sys.stdout,
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
```

However, I am still seeing these logs in my console output despite the condition being met:

```
[2020-04-28 13:31:11] INFO|django.request|GET /api/feed/rss/
[2020-04-28 13:31:13] INFO|django.request|GET /api/feed/rss/ - 200
HEEERRRRREEEE
```

Any ideas as to why these records are still being logged?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
I think what you want is to add your custom filter as the filter of `django.request` in the loggers section:

```
LOGGING = {
    'loggers': {
        'django.request':{
            'filters': ['skip_rss_requests'],
            'propagate': False, # stop it from propagating to parent
            # ... and other settings
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update: Sorry I misread the question.

Those `INFO|django.request` came from `django.request` loggers. When you set `'disable_existing_loggers': False` you are given the ability to redefine the default loggers, but in your logger settings you didn't overwrite the `djang.request` logger, that is why it is still using the default `django.request` logger.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

You can set DEBUG to False to disable showing the `INFO|django.request` logs

---

According to Django docs

> If you don’t want to configure logging at all (or you want to manually configure logging using your own approach), you can set LOGGING_CONFIG to None

```
# settings.py
LOGGING_CONFIG = None

import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(...)
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#disabling-logging-configuration

Comment: Unfortunately I want all the `INFO|django.request` logs. Just not for this particular endpoint. I have tried the things that you have suggested but still seeing all logs to that endpoint

Comment: @COB did you put that `skip_rss_requests ` filter as the filter on the `django.request` logger? i don't see it in your code snippet.

Comment: like this?: 
`  'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            'filters': ['skip_rss_requests'],
        },`

Comment: @COB yeah, I think it should be part of that logger

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes. I appreciate the help tho :)

Comment: @COB is it possible that you passed in 'propgate: True' and it let the parent logger, 'django', to also handle it? So, try setting it to False?

Comment: Have `propagate` set to `False` and still seeing the exact same logs

Comment: @COB one final thing....could you also apply that filter in the `django.server` logger? if you are running this code with "python manage.py runserver" it's going to use `django.server` to log the same thing. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#django-server

Comment: I've tried that but as you can see from the console output, those logs are coming from: `INFO|django.request`

Comment: in case you are interested, I posted the solution. I will upvote your helpful comments anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

in the end, this what worked:

```
def skip_rss_requests(record):
    if  hasattr(record, 'request') and hasattr(record.request, 'path') and '/rss/' in record.request.path:
            return False
    return True
```